# Symfony2: Delete entity through post request (improvements required)

Tags: forms, symfony, controller, entity

I need some improvements about my actual way to delete entities:

```
    public function deleteAction($path)
    {
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(array('path' => $path))
        ->add('path')
        ->setReadOnly(true)
        ->getForm();

    if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() === 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $image = $this->getImageManager()->findImageByPath($path);
            $this->getImageManager()->deleteImage($image);

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('AcmeImageBundle_Image_index'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeImageBundle:Image:delete.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Two improvements I already found while writting:

1. CreateFormBuilder in extra method in controller
2. Hidden field and overgive extra image-entity to get rendered

Are there other thing I could make better?

Regards

Comment: I try to merge the delete functionality into my form handler. Unfortunatly the form handler tries to map the form into the data_class of the form what is totally bullshit when I want to delete an entity. Is there an easy way to disable the data class defined in the ImageType class?

Comment: when you say delete an entity you mean delete an object of the entity no? If i'm true so you just have to do something like that: `$em->remove($entity);` this will delete your object and his line in your database (if your entity is related to the database)

Comment: Hi, youre right. In my example I use a service which manages database interactions. So this is alright. My question is how I improve semantic quality in handling deleting operations with a formhandler

Answer (score 1):

(my answer is too long for the comment so i add it here)

First you have to create a Type file (generally in YourApp\YourBundle\Form\yourHandler.php), some basique code to put inside if you don't know:

```
<?php
namespace ***\****Bundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

use ***\****Bundle\Entity\your_entity;

class *****Handler
{
protected $form;
protected $request;
protected $em;

public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->form    = $form;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->em      = $em;
}

public function process()
{
    if( $this->request->getMethod() == 'POST' )
    {
        $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

        if( $this->form->isValid() )
        {
            $this->onSuccess($this->form->getData());

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public function onSuccess(your_entity $object)
{
    // Make your stuff here (remove,....)
}
}
```

And in your controller i just call it this way:

```
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    $formHandler = new *****Handler($my_form, $this->get('request'), $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager());
    $formHandler->process();
}
```

Hope i'm clear enough

Comment: Hi, thank you for youre detailed description. I am already using such a FormHandler. The issue is that the formHandler only covers the create and update actions. A delete form handler would only have to create hidden id field and in the success method delete the instance of the entity marked with the given id. The question now is how I can merge the create/update formHandler together with the delete Formhandler

Comment: Hum i don't know, you can try to pass a variable to the handler which precise the type of action and just add if/else in your onSuccess method. What are you trying to do exactly? Why use a formHandler to delete an entity?